# Observer not firing

Tags: module, cart, event-observer, magento-1, price

Can you see why my observer is not firing?

config.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <chdispatcher>
                <class>Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model</class>
            </chdispatcher>
        </models>

        <frontend>
            <events>
                <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                    <observers>
                        <modify_to_custom_price>
                            <class>Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>modifyPrice</method>
                        </modify_to_custom_price>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            </events>
        </frontend>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php:

```
    <?php
Mage::log('Im here')
or exit("unable to log");
class Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model_Observer
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
    {
        // Get the quote item
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        Mage::log('Get Quote Item '. var_dump($_item->debug());

        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        Mage::log('Get parent item ' . var_dump($_item->debug());

        // Load the custom price
        //$price = "your custom price logic";
        $price = Mage::registry('dynamic_tier_price');
        Mage::log('Price is ' . $price);

        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        Mage::log('Item after super mode ' . var_dump($_item->debug());
    }



}
?>
```

---

Both @airhorse and @philwinkle had the correct answers. I had to do all of these things for it to work.

Comment: coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/ has the classname all lowercase like that in config so that's how I did it, but I'm seeing it out there other ways..

Comment: Is your module registered in app/etc/modules?

Comment: e.g. Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice.xml

Comment: Yes and I've verified in system>config>advanced > list of modules

Comment: I added what you see above.

Comment: Anyone help me regard observer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/279514/57334

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few things:

The model is defined as:

```
<class>Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model_Observer</class>
```

Which is looking for the class file in the folder structure `Caitlinhavener/Dynamicprice/Model/Observer/Observer.php`.

Change this line to:

```
<class>Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model</class>
```

Likewise, you have an issue in the model/method in your event listener - change to:

```
<class>chdispatcher/observer</class>
```

**Edit:**

Frontend should not be nested inside of `<global>`:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <chdispatcher>
            <class>Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model</class>
        </chdispatcher>
    </models>
</global>


<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <modify_to_custom_price>
                    <class>chdispatcher/observer</class>
                    <method>modifyPrice</method>
                </modify_to_custom_price>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: Also, consider renaming the `dispatcher` class name to `chdispatcher` or something not so generic and potentially namespace conflicting.

Comment: So I made your changes.. and I added something to cart then went to my var/log/system.log to see if any of my Mage::logs did anything. There's nothing. Does that mean its still not firing?

Comment: Did you clear cache, etc.? Change the Mage::log('Im here'); to die(), etc. and ensure that logging is enabled in System > Config > Developer

Comment: Cleared cache, logging is enabled, triple verified that the module is enabled.. I'm not sure how to use die... still not working.

Comment: I'm reading php docs for die/exit.. I'll try

Comment: Do you have `modify_to_custom_price` in any other observers??

Comment: No this is a clean site with not many modules. This is the only module I've developed on here.

Comment: Something I find weird... I have commercebug by Alan Storm and when I'm on the cart page if I view events, checkout_cart_product_add_after isn't even on there.. but it is the one I have been advised to use

Comment: Try putting `Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model_Observer` into `<class></class>`

Comment: Still not working :( I'm going to update the code above.

Comment: I think I found the problem - it wasn't obvious to me until you posted the new code.

Comment: @philwinkle can i get help regard observer? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/279514/57334

Answer (score 2):

You need to redeclare your models and take your events tag out of the frontend tag. See below.

```
<config>    
   <modules>
       <Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice>
   </modules>
   <global>
      <models>
           <dispatcher>
               <class>Caitlinhavener_Dynamicprice_Model</class>
           </dispatcher>
       </models>
       <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <modify_to_custom_price>
                        <class>caitlinhavener_dynamicprice/observer</class>
                        <method>modifyPrice</method>
                    </modify_to_custom_price>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
       </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Having events in frontend isn't wrong.

Comment: He's right about front end. Worked when I took it out.

Comment: Having events in frontend isn't wrong - having `<frontend>` in the wrong location, is.