# Magento Custom Module for add-to-cart Not Working - Observer Triggered

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, restriction

Created module like No other products add to cart if restricted product available in cart and vice versa.

My Module :

> app/etc/modules/Brst_Test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brst_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Brst_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This is my observer file

> app/code/community/Brst/Test/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Mage::log('fine dude', null, 'logfile.log');
class Brst_Test_Model_Observer
{
    //Put any event as per your requirement
    public function logCartAdd($observer) {
        // Mage::log('good dude', null, 'logfile.log');


        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0));
        $cart_qty = (int) Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

        if ($product->getId()==31588 && $cart_qty > 0) {
            Mage::throwException("You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it");
        }
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            if($productId==31588){
                Mage::throwException("Cart has Special Product you can not add another");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

> app/code/community/Brst/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brst_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Brst_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
             <brst_test>
                <class>Brst_Test_Model</class>
             </brst_test>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
            <events>
                <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                    <observers>
                        <Brst_Test_Model_Observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Brst_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>logCartAdd</method>
                        </Brst_Test_Model_Observer>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Not working, how to solve the error?

Comment: did you get anything in the log file.?

Comment: No, there is no any error in log file?

Answer (score 3):

> It should Work according to code.

**Try this if your not works**

- Ovverride `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php` to

  ```
     \app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php
  ```
- Find function `addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)` in your
  ovveride file, product add logic written in there
- add code after line `$request =
  $this->_getProductRequest($requestInfo);

`

```
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {

        $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
        $request = $this->_getProductRequest($requestInfo);

        /* ===========Restricted Product Coding Start==========        */
        $cart_qty = (int) Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
        $restrictedIds = array(1,2,3); //add restricted product ids here
        if (in_array($product->getId(), $restrictedIds) && $cart_qty > 0) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it');
           Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setHasError(true);
            return false;
        }

        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            if(in_array($productId, $restrictedIds)){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Cart has Special Product you can not add another');
           Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setHasError(true);
                return false;
            }
        }

        /* ===========Restricted Product Coding End ==========        */

        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product $helper */
        $helper  = Mage::helper('catalog/product');
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
}
```

**Note** : You can call observer overthere and put logic in your observer if you dont want to code in that function

Comment: Working good, but error error message not shown, eg: if i try add restricted product consider cart already have product, if click restricted product add-to-cart button message like product added to cart successfully. FYI -> product not added to cart, iis looking good, my only issue error message not shown properly. @Ketan Borada

Comment: i have update my answer, added line `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setHasError(true);`

Comment: still same error.  Product not add but error message not shown.

Comment: code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d19ac92c8eb5

Comment: working good for me try to debugging https://www.loom.com/share/d7501c1428a14e96ae887ff514db6a76

Comment: Could you please test with another condition pls.

Comment: i have checked both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95572/discussion-between-zus-and-ketan-borada).

Answer (score 2):

app\etc\modules\Brst_Test.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Brst_Test>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>community</codePool>
            </Brst_Test>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

app\code\community\Brst\Test\etc\config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config>
            <modules>
                <Brst_Test>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </Brst_Test>
            </modules>
            <global>
                <models>
                     <brsttest>
                        <class>Brst_Test_Model</class>
                     </brsttest>
                </models>
            </global>
            <frontend>
                    <events>
                            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
                                <observers>
                                    <brsttest>
                                        <type>singleton</type>
                                        <class>brsttest/observer</class>
                                        <method>logCartAdd</method>
                                    </brsttest>
                                </observers>
                            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
                        </events>
            </frontend>
        </config>
```

app\code\community\Brst\Test\Model\Observer.php

```
    <?php
    class Brst_Test_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {

        public function logCartAdd($observer){

            //I am change this
            $id = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('product');

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

            $cart_qty = (int) Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

            // I am change this
            if ($product->getId() == '31588' && $cart_qty > 0) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it');
                $url = Mage::getModel('core/url')->getUrl("checkout/cart");
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                exit;
            }

           $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                if($productId ==  '31588'){
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Cart has Special Product you can not add another');
                    $url = Mage::getModel('core/url')->getUrl("checkout/cart");
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                    exit;

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Try this code

Comment: Thanks for your reply, not working still other products added to cart if restricted products available in cart. code -> https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1597f887f17 @Vijay-CyberLocker

Comment: In your code also same, observer triggered, but condition not working @Vijay-CyberLocker

Comment: Ok brother give me few minutes i will update my answer.

Comment: i just want to know if my class right in observer class : <class>brst_test/observer</class> in config.xml

Comment: Still adding other products.

Comment: Have you check module register in this table core_resource?

Comment: My module is not available in the table core_resource,  how to add?

Comment: refresh and cache clear then check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95485/discussion-between-zus-and-vijay-cyberlocker).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95485/discussion-between-zus-and-vijay-cyberlocker